# Pushing data to all devices when database changes with Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, synchronization, realm

I know that Realm offers two way syncing and can trigger server-side events when data changes.

I am making a sort of messaging app, my question is how would I implement it so that when someone writes a message (which will update the DB), how does this message immediately display on other devices?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to open the same Realm on all devices, then they will all see the changes instantly as they happen (as long as they are connected of course :-)).

Check out the tutorial, it shows the data being realtime synced between both an iOS app, a Mac app and the Realm Browser: https://realm.io/docs/tutorials/realmtasks/

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers working on Realm Tasks, incorporating the latest features of the Realm Mobile Platform into it. :)

Making a chat app has become significantly easier with [the release of client Realm sharing in Realm 2.3](https://realm.io/news/realm-objc-swift-2.3/).

To make a chat app, the logic flow would be something like this:

1. A user starts a new chat room. This would be represented in RMP as a single, private Realm file belonging to that user.
2. The user can then invite other users access to that chat room via the sharing mechanism.
3. Every user can then contribute messages. Each message would be a separate Realm `Object` written to the shared Realm.
4. Each time a new chat message object is written to the Realm, it would be synchronized with every other user in the room.

Please let me know if you need any additional clarification.